# An error was encountered while retrieving the user profile

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, user-profile-service

I build a new SharePoint 2016 environment and migrated a site from old SharePoint 2016 environment to this one. After migration when I am trying to access following URL:

`https://www.example.com/sites/newsite/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties`

I am getting following error:

`An error was encountered while retrieving the user profile.`

The same URL works on old server but not new one. User Profile Service is working on both environments and it is attached to the web application.

Profile of logged in user exists. `My Sites` are not configured on both environments. I am at a loss to fix this issue. Please help.

Comment: Can you capture anything from the event viewer/ULS logs wile trying to access the url?

Comment: Found more detail from logs. `SPSecurityContext: Could not retrieve a valid windows identity for username ‘Contoso\User’ with UPN ‘User@ContosoNew.com’. UPN is required when Kerberos constrained delegation is used`. Basically, domain is Contoso but email is ContosoNew

Comment: And the user which is running Claims to Windows service has these permissions (Adjust memory quotas for a process, Log on as a batch job, Log on as a service, Replace a process level token, Impersonate a client after authentication)